# WPF: Problem with setting colums programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

i´m trying to build a storemanagment Application. I have already build the page with the products, which have buying options and so on. when someone buys the products, they´re moved to the ShoppingCart Window and here accours the error.

That the controls are not in the correct colum position. i want that every control is seperatet from eachother and not like in this case that they´re all put to the Left.

**Code**

```
decimal curCompletePrice = 0;

var rowcounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < _shoppingCartService.ArticlesDict.Count; i++)
{
    MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
}

foreach (var article in _shoppingCartService.ArticlesDict)
{
    if (article.Key != null)
    {
        var grid = new Grid();

        grid.MaxWidth = 800;
        Grid.SetRow(grid, rowcounter);

        var productImage = new Image();
        productImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(article.Value[0]));
        productImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        productImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        productImage.Height = 70;
        productImage.Width = 70;
        Grid.SetColumn(productImage, 0);

        var nameLabel = new Label();
        nameLabel.Content = article.Value[1];
        nameLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        nameLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        nameLabel.FontSize = 20;
        nameLabel.Height = 40;
        nameLabel.Width = 300;
        Grid.SetColumn(nameLabel, 1);

        var priceLabel = new Label();
        priceLabel.Content = article.Value[2];
        priceLabel.Content += "Euro";
        priceLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        priceLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        priceLabel.FontSize = 20;
        priceLabel.Height = 40;
        priceLabel.Width = 150;
        curCompletePrice += Convert.ToDecimal(article.Value[2]);
        Grid.SetColumn(priceLabel, 2);

        var quantityLabel = new Label();
        quantityLabel.Content = article.Value[3];
        quantityLabel.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        quantityLabel.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        quantityLabel.Margin = new Thickness(90, 0, 0, 0);
        quantityLabel.FontSize = 20;
        quantityLabel.Height = 40;
        quantityLabel.Width = 40;
        Grid.SetColumn(quantityLabel, 3);

        var CompletePrice = new Label();
        if (rowcounter == _shoppingCartService.ArticlesDict.Count -1)
        {
            CompletePrice.Content = "Gesamtsumme: " + curCompletePrice + " €";
            CompletePrice.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            CompletePrice.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            CompletePrice.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            CompletePrice.Margin = new Thickness(0, 300, 80, 0);
            CompletePrice.FontSize = 20;
            CompletePrice.Height = 40;
            CompletePrice.Width = 200;
            Grid.SetColumn(CompletePrice, 3);
        }

        grid.Children.Add(productImage);
        grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        grid.Children.Add(priceLabel);
        grid.Children.Add(quantityLabel);
        grid.Children.Add(CompletePrice);

        MainGrid.Children.Add(grid);

        rowcounter++;

    }
}
```

**Picture of problem**
[image]

**Update**

```
 <Window.DataContext>
 <local:ShoppingCartViewModel/>
 </Window.DataContext>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CartArticles}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="70" Source="{Binding PathPic}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="DimGray" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                <TextBlock Text=" x " FontSize="14" Foreground="DimGray" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Foreground="DimGray" Text="{Binding Price}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Why not using a ItemControl instead of a Grid?

Comment: @DanielW. did not now that this exist. i´m new to wpf

Comment: OK, is there any special issue why you create this in code and not in a xaml?

Comment: @DanielW. because the amount of products can be different. i can add one product. and it should only show one product in the shopping cart.

Comment: Thats what ItemControl is made for. Other options are DataGrid or StackPanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, let me mention, that WPF is desktop application. Not web-application or web-site, so your `i´m trying to build a store website` a little unclear. If you wan't web-site (e.g. web-application) - look into ASP.NET.

Secondary. Comment from @Daniel W. about using ItemsControl instead of Grid, in my opinion, should be expanded.

As you can see, you have a tonns of lines of code, where you **manually** rebuilding Grid and re-adding controls. It is hard to read and, as you come here, hard to debug.

What suggest @Daniel W. and me?

WPF was designed to use **Bindings**, to simplify interaction between UI and code-behind. For that purpose exists MVVM pattern (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm)), to separate Model (M), which is `article` in your example, View (V) which is your Window and View-Model (VM) which contains logic to manipulate over your Model (`article`).

What does it mean and how to use/implement it?

Let's split by parts:

1. **M** (Model). So, you have some `article` which represents a product someone gonna to purchase. It has, at least, Image, Name, Quantity, Price and Sum. So you can easily create a class, which will represent a single article:

```cs
using System;

namespace MVVMShoppingCart.Models
{
    public class CartArticle
    {
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Sum => Math.Round(Quantity * Price, 2);
        public string Currency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. **VM** (View-Model). This part responsible for "what to with articles" (or overall manipulating over articles). It may contain logic to add items, remove, edit quantities, etc. For simplicity, let's just "add" items into shopping cart. So we need some collection, where `CartArticles` will be stored and fill that collection with some items:

```cs
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using MVVMShoppingCart.Models;

namespace MVVMShoppingCart.ViewModels
{
    public class CartViewModel
    {
        // A collection, which stores articles in cart
        public ObservableCollection<CartArticle> CartArticles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CartArticle>();

        public CartViewModel()
        {
            // Fill for example with some articles
            Test_FillCartArticles();
        }

        private void Test_FillCartArticles()
        {
            CartArticles.Add(new CartArticle("banana.png", "Bananas", 1.234M, 1.99M, "Euro"));
            CartArticles.Add(new CartArticle("apple.png", "Apples", 2.345M, 0.99M, "Euro"));
            CartArticles.Add(new CartArticle("watermelon.png", "Watermelon", 5.05M, 1.49M, "Euro"));
        }
    }
}
```

3. **V** (View). Finally, the time to decide, how you want to display **M**odel in UI (in View, in Window). Instead of creating and adding manually controls to a Window, we suggest you to create a **template**. Template, by which should some items be displayed. And here comes @Daniel W. suggestion about `ItemsControl`.

`ItemsControl` is a container, which can store, obsiously, items, where Item - is our Model (`CartArticle`). It is similar to Grid by purpose, but by functionality it allows to easily define a template to display same items in same layout. Let's say, layout looks like:

[image]

You can use `Grid` to markup such "table" with Column and Row definitions.

```xml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <!-- Article image -->
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <!-- Article name -->
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
                <!-- Article quantity and price -->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <!-- Article quantity -->
                    <TextBlock />
                    <!-- Quantity and price "separator" -->
                    <TextBlock Text=" x " />
                    <!-- Article price -->
                    <TextBlock />
                </StackPanel>
                <!-- Article sum and currency -->
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <!-- Article sum -->
                    <TextBlock />
                    <!-- Article currency -->
                    <TextBlock />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now you have **1** template **for each** item in cart. No matter now many items you'll add - they will be layouted similarly. Now you just need to bind everything up:

- bind View (Window) with View-Model (`CartViewModel`) by providing view-model as `DataContext` property of View. For example, it may be done this way:

```xml
<Window x:Class="MVVMShoppingCart.Views.CartView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MVVMShoppingCart.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Shopping cart" Width="800" Height="450">
    <!-- 
        Setting CartViewModel as DataContext of Window.
        xmlns "viewModels" specified above
    -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:CartViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <!-- ... -->
</Window>
```

- bind collection in View-Model with `ItemsControl` to provide collection as source of items which ItemsControl should contain:

```xml
<!-- As we already set DataContext - you'll able to access the collection through the CartArticles property in CartViewModel -->
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CartArticles}">
```

- bind `CardArticle` properties with controls in template. As `ItemsControl` has a `ItemsSource` of `CartArticle`s collection, you'll able to access its properties to bind to them. For example, to display `CartArticle.Name` in `TextBlock`, use binding on `Text` property of `TextBlock` such as:

```xml
<!-- Article name -->
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

Repeat bindings for other `CartArticle` properties, append some styling and you may get such result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the very long but good Explanation. Could understand a lot, where i was confused

Comment: could you when you like, see the update in my xaml Code. because the desgin isnt showing when starting the program

Comment: @A.M what you mean "isn't showing"? Provide a screenshot

Comment: Full XAML from example you can check here: https://pastebin.com/f52NHk8Y. Because your updated XAML isn't full so I can't say it is potentially correct

Comment: thanks, i found the problem it was in the viewModel Code