# WPF: How to get the Current Object from a List when a Button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, buttonclick

**Problem**
I want to delete one article from a ObserableCollection when i Press the Red "X".
But i don´t know how to get the Current Artcile. I have a class Artcile. and the list which saves the different Articles.

**Xaml Code**

```
 <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CartArticles}">
 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="30,30,30,30" Margin="0,15,0,30" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="600" >
             <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" Grid.Row="0">
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition />
                     <ColumnDefinition />
                     <ColumnDefinition />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                 <Image Width="100" Height="70" Source="{Binding PathPic}" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
                 <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Grid.Column="1" FontSize="17" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="17" Foreground="DimGray" Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                     <TextBlock Text=" x " FontSize="16" Foreground="DimGray" />
                     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="17" Foreground="DimGray" Text="{Binding Price}" />
                     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="17" Foreground="DimGray" Text=" Euro" />
                 </StackPanel>

                 <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Grid.Column="2" FontSize="17" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Text="{Binding CompleteArticlePrice}"/>
                     <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="17" Foreground="DimGray" Text=" Euro" />
                 </StackPanel>
                 <Button Name="DeleteCartArticle" Grid.Column="2" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,13,20,0" Content="X" FontSize="15" Foreground="Red" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="DeleteCartArticle_Click"/>
             </Grid>
         </Border>
     </DataTemplate>
 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**ObserableCollection**

```
public ObservableCollection<Article> CartArticles { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Article>();

public void GetCartArticles()
{
    foreach (var article in _shoppingCartService.CartArticles.ToList())
    {
        CartArticles.Add(new Article
        {
            ArticleId = article.ArticleId,
            Name = article.Name,
            Price = article.Price,
            Quantity = article.Quantity,
            PathPic = article.PathPic,
            CompleteArticlePrice = article.Price * article.Quantity,
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Check datacontext of the button

Comment: Instead of using a Click event handler, you would typically bind the Button's Command property to an ICommand in the view model that contains the CartArticles property. The actual item would be provided to the ICommand by binding the Button's CommandParameter property. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14056939/1136211

Comment: @RandRandom thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice to see you're keep progressing from [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77387084/wpf-problem-with-setting-colums-programatically/77388579) :)

As @Clemens suggested, for buttons in MVVM you should use bindings too, and commands, which will handle click actions. But in case you use `ItemsControl` (not `ListView` or `ListBox`, which has `SelectedItem` proeprty to simplify our life) there is a little trick with button binding (described in XAML example-part below).

So, first of all you need to create a custom class which implements `ICommand` interface from `System.Windows.Input` namespace. Custom command class should accept some `object` as parameter, and that "object" is an item from `ItemsControl`. So, let's call it `ParameterizedCommand`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace YourNamespace.Commands
{
    public sealed class ParameterizedCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _action;

        public ParameterizedCommand(Action<object> action) => _action = action;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
        public void Execute(object parameter) => _action(parameter);

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your ViewModel (which is `CartViewModel` from previous answer) add command to remove `CartArticle` from `CartArticles` collection:

```cs
public class CartViewModel
{
    // A collection, which stores articles in cart
    public ObservableCollection<CartArticle> CartArticles { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CartArticle>();

    private ICommand _removeCartArticle;
    public ICommand RemoveCartArticle => _removeCartArticle ?? (_removeCartArticle = new ParameterizedCommand(parameter =>
    {
        // Ensure that received parameter is CartArticle
        var cartArticle = parameter as CartArticle;
        if (cartArticle == null)
            return;

        CartArticles.Remove(cartArticle);
    }));

    // ...
}
```

And finally, in your View bind button to that command. To allow button in item template "find" ViewModel and stored command, you can use `RelativeSource`, which is parent `ItemsControl`, and as `CommandParameter` we passing the item itself:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CartArticles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>               
            <!-- ... -->                   
            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.RemoveCartArticle}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            <!-- ... -->   
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now "delete" button in each `CartArticle` on click will remove that item from a collection. Just don't forget again append some styling:

[image]